# GLSurfaceView in LinearLayout Follow Up Question

Tags: android

Please see this question I asked a few days ago: [GLSurfaceView in LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980933/glsurfaceview-in-linearlayout)

The answer that was given worked very well... but I would like to know if there is a more detailed explanation on why this works?

From my comments, "Working with other view types, and looking at the examples provided for LinearLayout, using wrap_content should work AFAIK. Can you provide any documentation links or further explanation?"

"Is the issue with the GLSurfaceView wanting too much space initially when wrap_content is used?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because GLSurfaceView does not have the notion of "content." So when you tell a SurfaceView to have a height="wrap_content" it grabs all of the available space.

Comment: Alright, I get it. I suppose I shouldn't have blown 50 rep on this but I hate taking things for granted. I wonder why the use of something like this isn't documented as a correct way to handle views of this type in a LinearLayout... Thanks again.